# Concat List of columns passed as Parameter in Databricks

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I want to concat a list of column names that i am receiving as Input from ADF in Databricks by using
`dbutils.widgets.text('Primary_Key_Columns',"") Primary_Key = dbutils.widgets.get('Primary_Key_Columns')`

now i am using below code to concat all the columns in the list to make it one column. buit i am geting error stating such column doesn't exist.

```
   .withColumn('PK_Col', f.concat(Primary_Key))
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

if you providing a list of columns, then you need to convert a text value obtained via `Primary_Key = dbutils.widgets.get('Primary_Key_Columns')` into a real list by splitting it by some separator (`,`, `|`,  , whatever you use:

```py
Primary_Key = dbutils.widgets.get('Primary_Key_Columns')
cols = Primary_Key.split(",")
df = df.withColumn('PK_Col', f.concat(cols))
```